# part of jQuery script doesn't run in Drupal 6.28

Tags: jquery, drupal-6

I wrote a small jQuery script that runs in a Drupal site. The site is running jQuery 1.7.1. Everything works fine in jsFiddle, but when I run it in Drupal, part of the script doesn't work. Not sure if this is a Drupal thing or if I have something wrong with my code?

This is for a self-tests on an educational site. The content is arranged in slide toggles on the page. Inside some of the slide toggles are these self tests. They don't write to the database, they're just for the user.

The objective here is to make the self tests reset when the slide toggle is closed. Here's the jQuery:

```
$("h2.titleTrigger").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

//TOGGLE OPEN/CLOSE THE DRAWER
$(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("fast");

//UNDO THE SELF TEST
$('.selfTestWrong').removeClass('answerShown');
$('input:radio').prop('checked', false);
$('.selfTestAnswer').slideUp(300);

return false;
});


//self test

$('input:radio').bind('change',function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
var parentId = $(this).parents('.selfTest').attr('id');
$('#'+parentId+' .selfTestWrong').addClass('answerShown');
$('#'+parentId+' .selfTestAnswer').slideDown(300);
});
```

you can see it working correctly here: http://jsfiddle.net/bRFXb/

The problem is that when I run this in Drupal, everything works fine except for the part that resets the self test. When I close and open the slide toggle, nothing resets. No errors show in Chrome's Developer Tools. EDIT: The script loads at the bottom of the page immediately before the  tag. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this code after the page load in drupal. I think that will work like charm

Comment: The script loads in the footer of the page, immediately before the </body> tag.

Comment: When I replace the first $ with $document.ready(), it makes the answer div bounce in and out when I select a radio button, the button doesn't select but the wrong answers dim and don't reset when I close the toggle.